# Scala regex: get value from giver string

Tags: regex, scala

So i have this kind of `string`:

```
val str = "\n  Displaying names 1 - 20 of 273 in total"
```

And i want to return `Int` of the total number of names, in my example: `273`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scala> import scala.util.matching.Regex
import scala.util.matching.Regex

scala> val matcher = new Regex("\\d{1,3}")
matcher: scala.util.matching.Regex = \d{1,3}

scala> val string = "\n  Displaying names 1 - 20 of 273 in total"
string: String =
"
  Displaying names 1 - 20 of 273 in total"

scala> matcher.findAllMatchIn(string).toList.reverse.head.toString.toInt
res0: Int = 273
```

Obviously, adjust `\\d{1,3}` to suit your requirements where the lenght of  numbers to match are between and including 1 and 3

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the overall structure of the sentence, but should do the trick:

```
val str = "\n  Displaying names 1 - 20 of 273 in total"

val matches = """of\s+(\d+)\s+in total""".r.findAllMatchIn(str)

matches.foreach { m =>
  println(m.group(1).toInt)
}
```