# Get amount from giver string using Regex

Tags: regex, scala

So i have this string:

```
val value = "\nValue is €2,927"
```

How can i parse this amount `2927`, of **any** currency, and convert it to `double/int` ?

This is what i have try:

```
println(value.replaceAll("d{5}", ""))
```

Edit:

`€` could be any currency sign.

Comment: What if the value is `Value is €2,927.99`? Note that `d{5}` just matches 5 letters `d`. Is the currency value always the first int/float value you want to extract?

Comment: Or worst: `Value is €2 972.99, thanks.`

Comment: I need to use Regex with that ? (can i have code example ?)

Comment: Check http://ideone.com/O0i8oA and please let know if it works for you. It only shows how to get an int, but it can adjusted to check if a double was matched.

Comment: What i need to change in order to find also double ? (int or double)

Comment: Also my number 2,927 should be as Int or Double so it should be 2927

Comment: Are you always going to have one set of number in the string? i.e: can you have this `val value = "\nValue is €2,927 or £2600"`?

Comment: Sometimes it will be €2,927 and sometimer €999, can i use .replaceAll(",", "") at the end ?

Comment: Check http://ideone.com/ZDdpgG

Answer (score 2):

This may not be a definitive answer to your question (I'm not a Scala coder) but I think it'll be useful anyway, combined with other answers and comments.

You made me think about creating a regex to identify **monetary amounts only**, ignoring other numbers. This is what I came up with:

```
([$£€¥₹])?(\d{1,3}(?:[, ]?\d{1,3})?(?:.\d+)?)(?(1)|(kr\.?|Kč))
```

This example handles amounts pre-fixed with signs for dollars `$`, GB pounds `£`, Euro `€`, Japanese Yen (or Chinas Yuan Renminbi (?)) `¥` or Indian rupees `₹`.

It also handles currencies with a post-fixed currency "symbol". In the example Swedish/Danish/Norwegian kronor `kr` and Czech koruna `Kč`.

The amount is always captured in capture group 2. A prefixed currency symbol is in group 1, and a postfixed in group 3. (I figured - what good is the amount if you don't know the currency.)

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kL8pD9/1), handling this text:

> The cost of this car with a 3.5 litre engine, is €2,927.100, or $3 271.32. In Sweden that would be around 27000kr. I would have to work overtime for 215 days to save the money for that, even though my job in the Czech Republic pays 436.5Kč an hour, and I can save 10% percent of that. My buddy in Japan, bought one for ¥357014.83.

It starts by matching an optional currency sign. Then it matchers the amount, which can be formatted like any of `###`, `##,###`, `##,###,###.###`. After that it uses a regex condition - if the initial currency symbol was matched, it matches nothing -> done. If it wasn't matched, it tests for the post-fixed currency types.

The code (shooting from the hip here - no Scala experience what so ever, just a "googler"):

```
val value = "\nValue is €2,927"
val pattern = "([$£€¥₹])?(\\d{1,3}(?:[, ]?\\d{1,3})?(?:.\\d+)?)(?(1)|(kr\\.?|Kč))".r
val pattern(c1, amnt, c2) = value
// remove spaces and thousands-separators from the value
val str = amnt.replaceAll("[ ,]", "")
// convert it to an integer and/or double.
val i = str.toInt
val d = str.toDouble
```

---

**Edit**

Wow! This was a tough one to crack. I've now learnt that java regex doesn't support `if-else` constructs. So here's an alternative, little bit more complicated alternative:

```
(?=[$£€¥₹])(.)(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})?(?:\.\\d+)?)|(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})?(?:\.\d+)?)(kr\.?|Kč)
```

It uses a positive look-ahead to determine if it's a pre-fixed, or a post-fixed currency symbol. The actual amount capturing had to be split into two groups depending on *pre* or *post*. So either currency is in group 1 and amount in 2, or amount in 3 and currency in 4.

[And see **functioning** ;) code here at ideone](http://ideone.com/hSw8Qj).

**Edit #2**

Some new currencies and stuff added after comment.

```
(Rs.|[$£€¥₹])?\s*(\d{1,3}(?:[, ]?\d{1,3})?(?:.\d+)?)(?(1)|\s*(kr\.?|Kč|INR|€))
```

[Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kL8pD9/6).

Comment: Was looking at your profile, and so the "most unappreciated" answer. The complexity of this regex throws me off ;) But to add a little more to it if you want, french people likes to do things not like everybody, and so, the currency is written with € post-fixed and thousands could be space separated ;) : ie `€2,927.100` would be written in France : `2 927,10€` or `2 927.10€` or  `2927,10€` or `2927.10€` :D

Comment: @Esteban Thanks! Fixed and added as examples. :)

Comment: Sorry to say this, but NOW I have but no choice to upvote it, and so making this answer no longer you "most unappreciated" :p

Answer (score 0):

You could have a similar solution from my my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549167/scala-regex-get-value-from-giver-string/37549508#37549508).
So:

```
scala> import scala.util.matching.Regex
import scala.util.matching.Regex

scala>  val matcher = new Regex("\\d{1,1}")
matcher: scala.util.matching.Regex = \d{1,1}

scala> val value = "\nValue is €2,927"
value: String =
"
Value is €2,927"

scala> matcher.findAllMatchIn(value).toList.mkString.toInt
res1: Int = 2927
```

EDIT: Should accommodate doubles...

```
scala> val value = "\nValue is €2,927.545"
value: String =
"
Value is €2,927.545"

scala>  val matcher = new Regex("\\d{1,3}[\\.\\,\\ ]?[0-9]$*")
matcher: scala.util.matching.Regex = \d{1,3}[\.\,\ ]?[0-9]$*
scala> matcher.findAllMatchIn(value).toList.mkString.replaceAll("[ ,]", "").toDouble
res7: Double = 2927.545
```

And for spaces...

```
scala> val value = "\nValue is €2 927, 927.545"
value: String =
"
Value is €2 927, 927.545"

scala> matcher.findAllMatchIn(value).toList.mkString.replaceAll("[ ,]", "").toDouble
res8: Double = 2927927.545
```

Comment: OK thats fine but if my string is €2,927.9 this return 29279 instead of 2927.9, what should be added in order to support double & int ?

Comment: Ah I see. See my edit