# I want to match money amount with regex for indian currency without commas

Tags: python, regex

I want to match amount like **`Rs. 2000 , Rs.2000 , Rs 20,000.00 ,20,000 INR 200.25 INR.`**

Output should be
2000,2000,20000.00,20000,200.25

The regular expression i have tried is this

```
(?:(?:(?:rs)|(?:inr))(?:!-{0,}|\.{1}|\ {0,}|\.{1}\ {0,}))(-?[\d,]+    (?:\.\d+)?)(?:[^/^-^X^x])|(?:(-?[\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:(?:\ {0,}rs)|(?:\      {0,}rs)|(?:\ {0,}(inr))))
```

But it is not matching numbers with `inr` or `rs` after the amount
I want to match it using re library in Python.

Comment: Try `(?:Rs\.?|INR)\s*(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)|(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)\s*(?=Rs\.|INR)`

Comment: Use this tool to edit your regex https://www.debuggex.com/r/DRqJhtKxJhpYr3IB

Comment: [Check my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37567406/get-number-from-giver-string-using-regex/37571199?s=1|0.3736#37571199). It might assist you.

Comment: down vote
accept
 

I dont want to match commas in amount.

(?:Rs.?|INR)\s*(\d+(?:[.][^,]\d+))|(\d+(?:[.][^,]\d+))\s*(?:Rs.?|INR)

but this is not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using alternation group with capture groups inside to only match the numbers before  or after your constant string values:

```
(?:Rs\.?|INR)\s*(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)|(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)\s*(?:Rs\.?|INR)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rK7tL8/2).

**Pattern explanation**:

- `(?:Rs\.?|INR)\s*(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)` - Branch 1:

  - `(?:Rs\.?|INR)` - matches `Rs`, `Rs.`, or `INR`...
  - `\s*` - followed with 0+ whitespaces
  - `(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)` - Group 1: one or more digits followed with 0+ sequences of a comma or a dot followed with 1+ digits
- `|` - or
- `(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)\s*(?=Rs\.?|INR)` - Branch 2:

  - `(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)` - Group 2 capturing the same number as in Branch 1
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(?:Rs\.?|INR)` - followed with `Rs`, `Rs.` or `INR`.

Sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?:Rs\.?|INR)\s*(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)|(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)\s*(?:Rs\.?|INR)')
s = "Rs. 2000 , Rs.3000 , Rs 40,000.00 ,50,000 INR 600.25 INR"
print([x if x else y for x,y in p.findall(s)])
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/n4ydOH)

**Alternatively, if you can use PyPi `regex` module**, you may leverage *branch reset* construct `(?|...|...)` where capture group IDs are reset within each branch:

```
>>> import regex as re
>>> rx = re.compile(r'(?|(?:Rs\.?|INR)\s*(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)|(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)\s*(?:Rs\.?|INR))')
>>> prices = [match.group(1) for match in rx.finditer(teststring)]
>>> print(prices)
['2000', '2000', '20,000.00', '20,000', '200.25']
```

You can access the capture group in each branch by ID=1 (see `match.group(1)`).

Comment: For the branch reset: +1

Comment: down vote
accept
 

I dont want to match commas in amount.

(?:Rs.?|INR)\s*(\d+(?:[.][^,]\d+))|(\d+(?:[.][^,]\d+))\s*(?:Rs.?|INR)

but this is not working

Comment: If you do not want to match whole values with commas, use `(?:Rs\.?|INR)\s*(\d+(?:[.]\d+)*)\b(?!\,)|(?<!\d\,)\b(\d+(?:[.]\d+)*)\s*(?:Rs\.?|INR)` with the `re` module. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/rK7tL8/3). And [this IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/dxao9h).

Comment: Why is it returning *x* and *y* two values?

Comment: @ajinzrathod There are two capturing groups in the `re` pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Though slightly out of scope, here's a fingerplay with the newer and far superior **[`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex)** module by *Matthew Barnett* (which has the ability of subroutines and branch resets):

```
import regex as re

rx = re.compile(r"""
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<amount>\d[\d.,]+)    # amount, starting with a digit
    (?<currency1>Rs\.?\ ?)  # Rs, Rs. or Rs with space
    (?<currency2>INR)       # just INR
)

(?|
    (?&currency1)
    (?P<money>(?&amount))
|
    (?P<money>(?&amount))
    (?=\ (?&currency2))
)

""", re.VERBOSE)

teststring = "Rs. 2000 , Rs.2000 , Rs 20,000.00 ,20,000 INR 200.25 INR."
prices = [m.group('money') for m in rx.finditer(teststring)]
print prices

# ['2000', '2000', '20,000.00', '20,000', '200.25']
```

---

This uses subroutines and a branch reset (thanks to @Wiktor!).
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/fQ0mH5/3).

Comment: Nice one. Here is another [PCRE regex with conditionals](https://regex101.com/r/kI6iU7/2) I played with.

Comment: @bobblebubble: Good one as well!

Comment: The only problem is that you get this output: `['Rs. 2000', 'Rs.2000', 'Rs 20,000.00', '20,000 INR', '200.25 INR']` while OP needs only numbers. With the power of `regex` module, I'd rather use *branch reset*. See my updated answer.

Comment: Actually, in this case, `regex` module is redundant, you can do that with `re` as well. If you used capture groups with the same name (`re` does not allow that), it would make sense.

Comment: It does not, but it is not necessary here.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

I dont want to match commas in amount.

(?:Rs.?|INR)\s*(\d+(?:[.][^,]\d+))|(\d+(?:[.][^,]\d+))\s*(?:Rs.?|INR)

but this is not working

Comment: @VinaySawant: Please edit your original question and put your requirements there.

Answer (score 0):

And another:

```
(([\d+\,]+)(\.\d+)?\s\w{3}|(\w+\.?)\s?[\d+\,]+(\.?\d+))
```

Comment: Note that `+` inside a character class is treated as a literal `+`. Also, a comma is not a special character, no need to escape it here.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

I dont want to match commas in amount.

(?:Rs.?|INR)\s*(\d+(?:[.][^,]\d+))|(\d+(?:[.][^,]\d+))\s*(?:Rs.?|INR)

but this is not working