# Javascript Regex for Indian price validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate price format which can have values as eg. ₹ 3.50L,₹ 3.50, ₹ 3.50Cr,₹ 99.50L, ₹ 3L,₹ 300.50Cr, ₹ 350Cr, ₹ 3,50,000 ,₹ 1

I have tried this Regex : `^₹ ([0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*|[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)*(L|Cr))+$` which should fail for price ₹ 3,50L but it still show as pass.

What changes I need to make

Comment: Could you describe your rules in human-readable sentences? Also I don't quite get your use of point and comma.

Comment: Why do you think it should fail for the price `₹ 3,50L`? According to the regex you have there `([0-9]+(,[0-9]+)` and it fits the `3,50`

Comment: Maybe [`^₹ [0-9]+(?!,[0-9]+(?:L|Cr)?$)(?:,[0-9]+)*(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?:L|Cr)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/LVKHz7/2)?

Comment: price ₹ 3.50 is equivalent to $ 3.50 and if number has comma(,) then if should not be follwed by L or Cr. Also, number could either have . or , at a time followed by any number.

Comment: As already commented by Hubert Grzeskowiak, describe your rules in human-language so it will be possible to write the relevant regex according to what you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe my answer here can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37571199/2064981

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew , your regex works for all cases except price ₹ 3,500

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/LVKHz7/3

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew cases below ₹ 3,50L should not match: https://regex101.com/r/LVKHz7/4

Answer (score 0):

Following regex will get your work done:

```
^₹ (([0-9]+\,[0-9]+)|([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*(?:L|Cr)?))$
```

`([0-9]+\,[0-9]+)` : Will match values where **','** is used without **L** or **Cr**.

`([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*(?:L|Cr)?)` : Will match values with **L** or **Cr**. Here **'.'** may or may not be used.

[Use cases on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cDQLxo/2)