# Java Regex to Extract Euro Amount

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract the amount in Euro out of a string via a regular expression.

Presently I get only `5` as a result and cannot understand my error. How has a suitable solution to look like to detect also variants like `17,05 Euro` or `85 EUR` in my string?

```
    String regExp = ".*([0-9]+([\\,\\.]*[0-9]{1,})?) *[Eu][Uu][Rr][Oo]? .*";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);

    String input1 = "aerae aerjakaes jrj kajre kj 112123 aseraer 1.05 Eur aaa";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input1);
    matcher.matches();
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Result:

`5`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37571199/2064981). Might help you ;) At [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kL8pD9/7) modified.

Comment: `.*?` non-greedy and no need to escape `,.` in `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only get `5` because the first `.*` is *greedy* and grabs the whole line at first, then backtracks yielding character by character until the subsequent subpatterns match. That is why the last digit is only captured since only 1 is required by your pattern.

You may use a simpler pattern with `Matcher#find`:

```
String regExp = "(?i)([0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]+)?)\\s*euro?";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
String input1 = "aerae aerjakaes jrj kajre kj 112123 aseraer 1.05 Eur aaa";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input1);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/7dsHA6)

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier  (no need to write `[eE][Uu]`...)
- `([0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]+)?)` - Group 1:

  - `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
  - `(?:[.,][0-9]+)?` - an optional sequence of:

    - `[.,]` - a literal `.` or `,` symbols
    - `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `\\s*`  - 0+ whitespaces
- `euro?` - a `eur` or `euro` substring.

You may even reduce `[0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]+)?` to `[0-9][.,0-9]*` subpattern to match a digit followed with 0+ digits, `.` or `,` if the text is written well.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
String regExp = ".*([0-9]+([\\,\\.]*[0-9]{1,})?) *[Eu][Uu][Rr][Oo]? .*";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);

String input1 = "aerae aerjakaes jrj kajre kj 112123 aseraer 1.05 Eur aaa";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input1);
matcher.matches();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

With:

```
String regExp = "(?i)\\d*\\.*,*\\d*\\s(euro?)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
String input1 = "aerae aerjakaes jrj kajre kj 112123 aseraer 1.05 Eur aaa";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input1);
if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));

}
```

This works for the variants you provided.